# Most efficient way to select max differences and other values in their row for several columns

Tags: mysql, database

First off, everything I know about mySql is self taught so please let me know if there's anything I'm doing wrong or inefficiently. I have a table with 30+ columns that kinda looks like this... (ignore actual values, this is to just give an idea what table looks like)

```
id  | uid  |  c1   |  c2  |  c3  |..cols 4-29...|  c30 |  time
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  15  |  234  |  11  |  21  |              |  18  |  2013-01-19 00:00:00
 2  |  96  |  311  |  29  |  23  |              |  27  |  2013-01-19 00:00:00
 3  |  13  |  443  |  31  |  33  |              |  35  |  2013-01-19 00:00:00
 4  |  97  |  345  |  44  |  47  |              |  48  |  2013-01-19 00:00:00
 5  |  85  |  271  |  53  |  49  |              |  52  |  2013-01-19 00:00:00
 6  |  96  |  273  |  62  |  50  |              |  64  |  2013-01-20 00:00:00
 7  |  13  |  449  |  54  |  57  |              |  87  |  2013-01-20 00:00:00
 8  |  97  |  374  |  93  |  59  |              |  62  |  2013-01-20 00:00:00
 9  |  85  |  851  |  71  |  87  |              |  74  |  2013-01-20 00:00:00
```

`id` is the primary key; `uid` is also indexed- it's the id value for each user that matches up with the user's name in another table called `user_names`. Then there are 30 columns of data and a timestamp field.

The table gets updated daily with new values for each user. I need to select the biggest difference over a time period for each column, and the name of who had that gain for each column. I have a few queries that work, but they're slow and seem very inefficient. For example:

```
SELECT tbl1.name as col1_name, tbl1.col1_diff, 
       tbl2.name as col2_name, tbl2.col2_diff FROM 

(SELECT pl.name, (MAX(c1)-MIN(c1)) as col1_diff FROM 
    `data_table` tbl JOIN `user_names` as pl ON tbl.pid=pl.id 
    WHERE time BETWEEN '2013-06-05 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-06 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY pid ORDER BY col1_diff DESC LIMIT 1) as tbl1 

JOIN (SELECT pl.name, (MAX(c2)-MIN(c2)) as col2_diff FROM 
    `data_table` tbl JOIN `user_names` as pl ON tbl.pid=pl.id 
    WHERE time BETWEEN '2013-06-05 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-06 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY pid ORDER BY col2_diff DESC LIMIT 1) as tbl2
```

That pulls the correct data for only the first 2 columns, ex:

```
col1_name | col1_diff | col2_name | col2_diff
------------------------------------------------
   josh   |   4124    |   steve   |   512
```

While I'd  prefer getting 1 row for each column instead of one total result row, I can at least work with this. But already this query takes ~0.5 seconds, and every join I add to calculate another column just adds to that time resulting in unacceptable query times.

I'm looking for ways to pull this data as fast as possible. I know the username join in each derived table is definitely slowing me down, but I couldn't come up with a way to pull each individual name with one big join at the end (if that's even the way to approach it?). I've tried quickly writing 1 query to pull the data for each row and looping through that 30 times but that's slow and seems even more inefficient to me. I've considered calculating each person's gains at the end of the day and storing them in a separate table, but I feel there has to be a better solution.

The page that will eventually display this data needs to show the top gaining user for each column and their gain, but I need to run the query 3 times with different date ranges (yesterday, last 7 days, and last 30 days); Any help or thoughts on the best way to approach this are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your columns c1 to c30? Since you are using MIN and MAX on them, an index should speed things up (but might slow down INSERTs, depending on how often/quick the appear). And I’d probably try sub-SELECTs instead of JOINs here, but that’s just a gut feeling …

Comment: Currently my only indexes are on the `id` and `uid` columns. I'll try indexing them all and see if that helps

Comment: When you’ve done that, use `EXPLAIN {your query}` to see whether the indexes are actually getting used (and all of them). If not, try sub-SELECTs instead of JOINs (I’m not sure if that’ll make a difference though).